# Python Dictionary Assist

Tags: python, dictionary

New to Python and am attempting to complete an assignment but stuck:

I know the basics of dictionaries but the program I'm supposed to write has me scratching my head.

1. Create a dictionary of stocks symbols w/prices (key/value) (did that)
2. The program prompts the user to input a stock symbol (key) (did that)
3. The program is then supposed to return the price associated with that specific symbol (value) (no luck)
4. If the user inputs a stock symbol not in the dictionary, the program is supposed to ask the user to input a 'valid' stock symbol.
5. Repeat

Here is the syntax I have.  It's not complete of course, as I cannot get it to return the value...

```
print("Please enter stock symbol in all CAPS for current price: ")

stock_symbol = input()

stock = {'ADBE': '$2', 'SPOT': '$3', 'BJ': '$4', 'DIS': '$5', 'FB': '$6', 'BABA': '$6','LOW': '$7', 'NLS': '$8', 'SONO': '$9', 'NEM': '$10'}

if stock_symbol == 'ADBE':

    print("ADBE is" + stock)
```

Comment: "get it to return the value": What does this mean?  Get *what* to return *what* to *where*?  What part of your code is attempting to do this?

Comment: Use `in` to see if the key exists. Then use it as an index to get the value: `if stock_symbol in stock: print(stock_symbol + " is " + stock[stock_symbol])`

Comment: Sorry, guess I wasn't clear enough. Get the program to return the value of the stock to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Just some (crucial) hints, as this is an assignment.

You need to look up the given key in the dictionary:

```py
value = stock[stock_symbol]
```

The "tricky" part is that the above will fail if `stock_symbol` is not in the `stock` dictionary. For this, you can use the `get()` method, which does not fail but returns `None` when the key is not found:

```py
value = stock.get(stock_symbol)
if value is None:
    print('not found')
else:
    print('found', value)
```

Other than that, `stock.get(key)` and `stock[key]` are equivalent.

Another solution is to check whether the key is in the dictionary prior to the actual lookup:

```py
if stock_symbol in stock:
    # stock_symbol is in stock. It may be looked up with stock[stock_symol]
else:
    # stock_symbol is not in stock. Do not attempt stock[stock_symbol]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value from a dictionary directly using `dict[key]` if `dict` is you dictionary.

So for you case, you can directly do: `stock[stock_symbol]`

For checking if the key exists in a dictionary, you can use the `in` keyword as:

```
if stock_symbol in stock
```

You can use the `while` loop for iterating until the value is found.